# mySQL Fetch Time Taking Way Too Long

Tags: mysql, networking, fetch

We have a mySQL database on Amazon RDS. Theres a table we pull from that pulls roughly 150k rows. The size of the data packet is 500KB, yet it's taking 10 seconds for the network to fetch?

The statement is pretty simple:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, b.col1, b.col2, c.col1, c.col2
FROM a  
JOIN b ON b.col1 = a.col1  
JOIN c  ON c.col1 = a.col2
```

The joined tables are very small (5-50 rows).

Table `a` is where all the rows are coming from.

We are using mySQL 5.7, so the buffer scaling should be automatic?

The DB has 2GB of ram.

EXPLAIN results [image]

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: I posted the EXPLAIN query

Comment: Thanks for the progress report

Comment: To be more clear, you have posted the EXPLAIN report, but you have not posted the other thing Strawberry asked for, which is the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for each of the three tables in your query. The reason this is requested is that people who answer your question want to know what data types, indexes, or constraints you already have in the table. They may want to test a query before they post an answer. Providing the full definition of your tables helps us help you!